# Show that there is no coefficient field containing $k(X+Y^p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, let $R = k(Y)[[X]]$ be the power series ring with coefficients in $k(Y)$.  Now $R$ is a local ring whose unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ consists of power series with constant term zero.  The map $\pi: R \rightarrow R/\mathfrak M \cong k(Y)$ is just evaluation at $X = 0$.  A field $F \subseteq R(Y)[[X]]$ is called a **coefficient field** if the image $\pi(F)$ is all of $k(Y)$.  I'm stuck on the following problem:

> Problem: Show that if $F \subseteq R$ is a field with $k(X + Y^p) \subseteq F \subseteq R$, then $F$ is not a coefficient field.

It is pretty easy to see that $k(X+Y^p)$ is itself not a coefficient field: regarding the elements of this field as power series in $X$, the constant terms all lie in $k(Y^p)$, and the image under $\pi$ is exactly $k(Y^p)$.

Now $k(Y^p) \subseteq k(Y)$ is a purely inseparable extension of degree $p$; there are no intermediate fields between these.  So I somehow have to show that the image of any field $F$ containing $k(X+Y^p)$ under $\pi$ is equal to $k(Y^p)$.

Comment: I don't really understand why $F = k(X+Y^p, Y)$ wouldn't be a counter-example.

Comment: Well, the field $k(X+Y^p)$ is not really contained in $R$; the ring $k[X+Y^p] \subseteq R$, then you can see that the nonzero elements of $k[X+Y^p]$ are units in $R$.

Comment: On the other hand, $k[X+Y^p,Y] \subseteq R$, but not every element in $k[X+Y^p,Y]$ has an inverse in $R$, for example $X$.  So it doesn't make sense to write $k(X+Y^p,Y) \subseteq R$.

Comment: since the beginning, didn't you mean $k(Y)(X)$ the field of formal Laurent series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_{n,k} Y^k) X^n $ ? in that case it contains $k(X+Y^p)$ the field of formal Laurent series $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} a_m (X+Y^p)^m$

Comment: No, everything here is contained in $k(Y)[[X]]$ (power series in the variable $X$ with coefficients in $k(Y)$).

Comment: I don't understand... what is $k[X+Y^p]$ ? the ring of power series in $X+Y^p$ ? why do you use a different notation for $k(Y)[[X]]$ (why not $k(Y)[X]$ ?)

Comment: single brackets mean polynomial ring, double brackets mean power series.  round brackets mean quotient field of what was in single brackets.  So $k(Y)[[X]]$ properly contains $k(Y)[X]$.  this is standard notation, right?